# what debugging tool you are using for react native app development

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi guys what debugging tools you use for react native?

i also want to get ram usage of the app what is your recommended app?

Comment: The question is for another platform  I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) which is a great debugging tool for `react-native`. For analyising network requests made by your application, Flipper's [network plugin](https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/plugins/network/) is very useful. For Android there exists a [LeakCanary Plugin](https://fbflipper.com/docs/features/plugins/leak-canary/) that enables support for [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), an open source memory leak detection library for Android, within Flipper.

For monitoring memory usage, I usually use XCode for iOS and Android Studio for Android directly.

1. **For iOS:** Start your App using XCode and launch [Instruments](https://help.apple.com/instruments/mac/current/#/dev7b09c84f5) via  `Xcode, choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments`.
2. **For Android:** Start your App using Android Studio and open the [Android memory profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler).

For performance profiling specifically there is a good documentation in the official [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/profiling).